# how to use D3.js in WebSphere Portal

Tags: d3.js, websphere-portal

I am trying to use D3.js in WebSphere Portal 8, our theme is a custom theme with dojo 1.9 in it. I tried to put the d3 js files in theme, but still no luck. I get a 404 javascript error saying that the d3.js is not found.

```
require(["d3/d3"], function(d3){...});
```

Comment: Not familiar with websphere-portal, but since the problem might be unrelated to that platform: 1) Make sure you're using a relatively recent version of d3, because older versions were not AMD (i.e. requirejs) -compatible. 2) Let's say that the file that's doing the requiring lives at `/some/path/to/js/main.js` then make sure the d3 soure is at `/some/path/to/js/d3/d3.js` (note that `d3.min.js` would not be loaded unless you require `"d3/d3.min"`). 3) since you're seeing a 404 error, did you ensure that the path on that error is the expected path to the file?

Comment: Have checked the path, looks good but still the same issue, might  be some compatible issues b/w dojo and d3 js in websphere portal.